# Razor Component not rendering

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a simple Razor component. The application builds but when I run it, there is nothing shown.

The Razor component (SystemNameLookup.razor) is

```
@inherits SystemNameLookupComponent
<h3>Hi @SystemName</h3>
```

and the code behind is

```
namespace WebApp.Pages.Shared.Components
{
    public class SystemNameLookupComponent : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string SystemName { get; set; } = "Something";
    }
}
```

and it is called as

```
<SystemNameLookup></SystemNameLookup>
```

_Imports.cshtml contains

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using WebApp.Pages.Shared.Components
```

and _ViewImports.cshtml contains

```
@using WebApp
@using WebApp.Pages.Shared.Components
@namespace WebApp.Pages
```

But nothing appears! What am I missing? (No errors reported -this was run on ASP.Net Core 5)

Comment: A solution seems to be <component type="typeof(WebApp.Pages.Shared.Components.SystemNameLokup)" render-mode="Static" … /> which means the bit that was wrong was the way I tagged it on the form. This seems different to several articles I have read so there are more unknowns

Comment: Chances are, like me, you read "Razor Component?", sounds great! That would work in Razor view engine and, hence, in 'Razor Pages', right? 

Nope.

All the examples you've seen where it 'just works', are in *Blazor*, not *Razor Pages*.  

This is often glossed over.  As you've found, you can use the Component tag helper to render them to Razor pages, but it's unclear to me what the prerequisites, overheads and limitations are.

Answer (score 0):

I test with my blazor project,and it can work.Here is a demo(My project name is BlazorApp_ServerSide,and I don't have `_ViewImports.cshtml` in my blazor app,you can refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/layouts?view=aspnetcore-5.0#apply-a-layout),`The _Imports.razor file is similar to the _ViewImports.cshtml file for Razor views and pages but applied specifically to Razor component files.`):

structure:

[image]

SystemNameLookup.razor:

```
@inherits SystemNameLookupComponent
<h3>Hi @SystemName</h3>
```

SystemNameLookupComponent.razor.cs:

```
namespace BlazorApp_ServerSide.Pages.Shared.Components
{
    public class SystemNameLookupComponent: ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string SystemName { get; set; } = "Something";
    }
}
```

_Imports.razor:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using BlazorApp_ServerSide
@using BlazorApp_ServerSide.Shared
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using BlazorApp_ServerSide.Pages.Shared.Components
```

Test.razor:

```
@page "/test"
<SystemNameLookup></SystemNameLookup>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can only assume that my project is neither fully razor or blazor and that is causing the problem. I see you have some @using's on Blazor that I do not have